# Unable to run minimal-ws-client-echo

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I'm currently trying to run a minimal example linked below:

https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/tree/master/minimal-examples/ws-client/minimal-ws-client-echo

for libwebsockets with a simple Python http server on localhost:7681. I'm getting an error:

```
    minimal-ws-client-echo jeffhotz$ ./minimal-ws-client-echo 
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1087] USER: LWS minimal ws client echo + permessage-deflate + multifragment bulk message
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1087] USER:    lws-minimal-ws-client-echo [-n (no exts)] [-u url] [-p port] [-o (once)]
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1087] USER: options 0, ads localhost
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1112] NOTICE: created client ssl context for default
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1113] USER: connecting to localhost:7681//
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1206] ERR: CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR: HS: URI missing
    [2019/06/11 15:55:03:1208] USER: Completed 3 failed
```

I'm clueless as to what the error is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm biased, but I'm also curious because I want to improve my library... Why libwebsockets and not [facil.io](http://facil.io)?

Comment: No reason in particular; I might give your library a try. Thanks.

Comment: Actually according to Wiki facil.io doesn't do client websockets which I need. But I have to say that the name makes it very attractive. (:

Comment: Oh... Which Wiki is that? I guess I need to update some documentation somewhere, because you **can** use [facil.io as a WebSocket client](http://facil.io/0.7.x/http#websocket-connections-client).

Comment: Thank you for your time, answering my question.

Comment: Yep, the Wikipedia page. It's updated now.